# Querying for RavenDB documents using multiple properties

Tags: ravendb

I need to make a query against a document collection that matches several properties.
(Cross post from the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/r5f1zr2jd_o)

Here is the document:

```
public class SessionToken
{
    [JsonProperty("jti")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("aud")]
    public Uri Audience { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sub")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("claims")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
[TestFixture] 
public class RavenDbTests 
{ 
    private IDocumentStore documentStore; 

    [SetUp]   
    public void SetUp() 
    { 
        this.documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { RunInMemory = true }; 
        this.documentStore.Initialize(); 
    } 

    [Test] 
    public async void FirstOrDefault_WhenSessionTokenExists_ShouldReturnSessionToken() 
    { 
        var c = new SessionToken() 
                { 
                    Audience = new Uri("http://localhost"), 
                    Subject = "NUnit", 
                    Claims = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                                { 
                                    { ClaimTypes.System, "NUnit" } 
                                } 
                }; 

        using (var session = this.documentStore.OpenAsyncSession())
        {
            await session.StoreAsync(c); 
            await session.SaveChangesAsync(); 

            // Check if the token exists in the database without using Where clause 
            var allTokens = await session.Query<SessionToken>().ToListAsync(); 
            Assert.That(allTokens.Any(x => x.Subject == "NUnit" && x.Audience == new Uri("http://localhost"))); 

            // Try getting token back with Where clause
            var token = await session.Query<SessionToken>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()).Where(x => x.Subject == "NUnit" && x.Audience == new Uri("http://localhost")).ToListAsync(); 
            Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(token.First().Id); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The last Assert is the one that is failing.
I must admit Im not sure whether this is a bug or a failure on my part.
As far as I understand, this is supposed to work.

PS. I´ve tried with a standalone document store as well as embedded without running in memory, but with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting stale results.  In a unit test, you need to allow time for indexing to occur.

Add `.Customize(x=> x.WaitForNonStaleResults())` to your queries and the test should pass.

Also, I think you left the `Id` property off your question when you cut/paste because it doesn't compile as-is.

**UPDATE**

Per discussion in comments, the issue was that you were applying the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the `Id` property.  Since the `Id` property represents the document key, and is not serialized as part of the JSON document, you can't apply the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to it.

Comment: Tried that today. The result is still the same.

BTW. Updated the original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: Your test passes for me.  Exactly as-is. What version/build are you using?

Comment: Ok. It seems the `SessionToken` class I posted above is not correct.
The problem occurs when I there is a `JsonProperty` attribute on the properties. I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: You can't use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute on the `Id` property.

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem. Is the fact that `[JsonProperty]` cannot be used on the `Id` property documented somewhere?

Comment: I can't find anywhere that says that explicitly, but understand that the `Id` property (or whichever property follows your identity convention), is a representation of the document key, and is *not actually stored inside the document*.  You can see this if you look at one of your documents in the RavenDB management studio.  So therefore, it can't be controlled through json serialization attributes, because it gets stripped out before serialization occurs.

Comment: Nice. Could you post the above comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution? :-)